# Performance issue with StanfordCoreNLP and Semantic Graph

Tags: graph, semantics, stanford-nlp

When I attempt to analyze text with Stanford-NLP and CoreNLP, the performance is very poor. Processing a document from CNN.com takes around 30 seconds.

The code I have basically creates a single instance of StanfordCoreNLP with the following configuration:

annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref
sutime.binders = 0

When I disable the "ner, parse, dcoref", the performance is very quick. Since I need to obtain the semantic graph, I was wondering if there was a way to optimize the performance or another way to obtain the semantic graph to retrieve things such as Direct Object, Noun Subject, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing and coreference resolution are often slow, but unfortunately there's no way to get subject and object information in the semantic graph in CoreNLP without running the `parse` and `dcoref` annotators. That said, Stanford CoreNLP is under active development and getting faster over time.